# Revison due date "by"?

Tags: paper-submission, deadlines

I have a question regarding the deadline for submitting a revised paper. Does "due date by" mean the day before or that very day?

I know it's better to not put myself in such situation in the first place, but for the worst case scenario, has anyone ever experienced a situation in which submitting the paper on the due date was unsuccessful? And the submission system has already closed on the due date?

I should add thet in the email sent by the editior, there was no specification of time, time zone or anything else. Just A simple "due date by"

Comment: I suspect that for a paper revision, they will interpret it generously. Conference submissions might be different. But if you are late, things might get delayed. But "end of day in your local time zone" is used by at least one organization. End of day Universal Time is a bit less generous. But, I think that "prior to beginning of day..." is very unlikely. But it's a big world with a lot of different customs.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Well if that's the case, its a big relief. Hope the journal be as generous.

Comment: I voted to close because the question is about a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience with academics, many of us will do things by the absolutely last moment. No person that knows what they are doing would set a deadline of "by January 11th" and expect everything to be done at January 11th 00:01.

When it comes to "deadlines" for submitting revised versions of journal articles (non special issue) are there predominately to avoid the case where authors just always prioritize something else and never get it done. The editorial systems I have worked with from the editor perspective would just auto-fill those in a few months time. But there is no real point for the editor to enforce those - it means that the work they've put in the refereeing process is for naught.

Comment: Exactly. Most editors are also happy to give extensions, unless this is for a special issue.

Comment: Even for a special issue, it's sometimes possible to get a (short) extension.  I've done that.